# Is it possible to combine these complex MYSQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I have two queries, both deliver an inventory.id, inventory.title, and an amount needed for orders.

What I would like to do is combine them so the the results of the column amount_needed_for_orders are summed together.

Here is a quick summary of what is going on. I am working on a bakery inventory management program. The baker has inventory, dough_recipes, and products which are fractions of dough recipes.

Here is where it gets complicated/hair pulling begins.

Each recipe has a list of ingredients, with a yield. 
***Some recipes have another recipe in them as an ingredient. This dough within a dough is known as a preferment and is also known as poolish.

One query delivers the amount of inventory needed for any orders with a preferment in them, the second query delivers the current inventory level along with the amount of inventory needed for the orders (not including any preferment ingredients).

Since it is complicated I am building it as I go. The next step would be to somehow combine these two queries.

Here is the amount of inventory needed for all orders (not including preferments):

```
SELECT SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds / dough_recipe_yield_pounds * weight *      
quantity_to_be_baked) as amount_needed_for_orders,id,title,inventory_pounds
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            inventory.id, 
            inventory.title, 
            products.weight, 
            products.id AS product_id, 
            (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS 
quantity_to_be_baked,
                CASE inventory.units
                    WHEN  'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * inventory.quantity
                END as inventory_pounds,
                CASE dough_recipes.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * dough_recipes.amount
                END  AS dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds, 
            (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS num_loaves_needed,
                CASE doughs.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * doughs.yield
                END AS dough_recipe_yield_pounds
            FROM inventory
            LEFT JOIN dough_recipes ON inventory.id = dough_recipes.inventory_id
            LEFT JOIN products ON dough_recipes.dough_id = products.dough_id
            LEFT JOIN orders_items ON products.id = orders_items.product_id AND 
(orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) > 0
            LEFT JOIN doughs ON doughs.id = products.dough_id
        ) sq
        GROUP BY id
```

Here is the amount of inventory needed for all order's preferments.

```
SELECT id,title, SUM(pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds / 
pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * quantity_to_be_prepared) as 
amount_needed_for_orders
        FROM (SELECT inventory.id,
                 inventory.title,
                 dough_pre_ferments.amount,
                 dough_pre_ferments.unit,
                 products.weight,
                 (order_preferments.quantity-order_preferments.quantity_prepared) as 
quantity_to_be_prepared,
          CASE pre_ferment_recipes.units
                WHEN 'kilograms'
                THEN 2.20462 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'pounds'
                THEN 1 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'ounces'
                THEN 0.0625 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'grams'
                THEN 0.00220462 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
          END  AS pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds,

          CASE pre_ferments.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * pre_ferments.yield
          END AS pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds

            FROM inventory
            LEFT JOIN pre_ferment_recipes ON pre_ferment_recipes.inventory_id = 
inventory.id
            LEFT JOIN dough_pre_ferments ON dough_pre_ferments.pre_ferment_id = 
pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            LEFT JOIN products ON products.dough_id = dough_pre_ferments.dough_id
            LEFT JOIN pre_ferments ON pre_ferments.id = 
pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            LEFT JOIN order_preferments ON order_preferments.preferment_id = 
pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            ) sq
            GROUP BY id
```

Comment: well from just looking at the amount of things you are doing with these queries.. trying to combine them would hurt performance greatly. can you post the schema? that would help a lot.

Comment: Performance is not an issue, this is only run by one guy at a time. Here is a link to the DB with some psuedo data. http://forfrom.com/db.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working solution to your question.

```
SELECT id, title, SUM(amount_needed_for_orders) 
FROM(
(SELECT id,title, SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds / dough_recipe_yield_pounds * weight *      
quantity_to_be_baked) as amount_needed_for_orders
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            inventory.id, 
            inventory.title, 
            products.weight, 
            products.id AS product_id, 
            (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS 
quantity_to_be_baked,
                CASE inventory.units
                    WHEN  'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * inventory.quantity
                END as inventory_pounds,
                CASE dough_recipes.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * dough_recipes.amount
                END  AS dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds, 
            (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS num_loaves_needed,
                CASE doughs.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * doughs.yield
                END AS dough_recipe_yield_pounds
            FROM inventory
            LEFT JOIN dough_recipes ON inventory.id = dough_recipes.inventory_id
            LEFT JOIN products ON dough_recipes.dough_id = products.dough_id
            LEFT JOIN orders_items ON products.id = orders_items.product_id AND 
(orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) > 0
            LEFT JOIN doughs ON doughs.id = products.dough_id
        ) sq
        GROUP BY id
) 
UNION ALL

(SELECT id,title, SUM(pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds / 
pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * quantity_to_be_prepared) as 
amount_needed_for_orders
        FROM (SELECT inventory.id,
                 inventory.title,
                 dough_pre_ferments.amount,
                 dough_pre_ferments.unit,
                 products.weight,
                 (order_preferments.quantity-order_preferments.quantity_prepared) as 
quantity_to_be_prepared,
          CASE pre_ferment_recipes.units
                WHEN 'kilograms'
                THEN 2.20462 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'pounds'
                THEN 1 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'ounces'
                THEN 0.0625 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'grams'
                THEN 0.00220462 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
          END  AS pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds,

          CASE pre_ferments.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * pre_ferments.yield
          END AS pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds

            FROM inventory
            LEFT JOIN pre_ferment_recipes ON pre_ferment_recipes.inventory_id = 
inventory.id
            LEFT JOIN dough_pre_ferments ON dough_pre_ferments.pre_ferment_id = 
pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            LEFT JOIN products ON products.dough_id = dough_pre_ferments.dough_id
            LEFT JOIN pre_ferments ON pre_ferments.id = 
pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            LEFT JOIN order_preferments ON order_preferments.preferment_id = 
pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            ) sq
            GROUP BY id
)
) as t
GROUP BY id
```

---

**EDIT:**

here is a working solution with joins.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.title, t.inventory_pounds, 
    t.amount_needed_for_orders + t1.amount_needed_for_orders
FROM(
    SELECT 
        id,title, inventory_pounds,
        SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds / dough_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * quantity_to_be_baked) AS amount_needed_for_orders
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            inventory.id, 
            inventory.title, 
            products.weight, 
            products.id AS product_id, 
            (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS quantity_to_be_baked,
                CASE inventory.units
                    WHEN  'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * inventory.quantity
                    WHEN  'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * inventory.quantity
                END AS inventory_pounds,
                CASE dough_recipes.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * dough_recipes.amount
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * dough_recipes.amount
                END  AS dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds, 
            (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS num_loaves_needed,
                CASE doughs.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * doughs.yield
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * doughs.yield
                END AS dough_recipe_yield_pounds
            FROM inventory
            LEFT JOIN dough_recipes ON inventory.id = dough_recipes.inventory_id
            LEFT JOIN products ON dough_recipes.dough_id = products.dough_id
            LEFT JOIN orders_items ON products.id = orders_items.product_id AND 
(orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) > 0
            LEFT JOIN doughs ON doughs.id = products.dough_id
        ) sq
        GROUP BY id
) AS t
JOIN
(   SELECT 
        id,title, 
        SUM(pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds / pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * quantity_to_be_prepared) AS amount_needed_for_orders
    FROM (SELECT inventory.id,
                 inventory.title,
                 dough_pre_ferments.amount,
                 dough_pre_ferments.unit,
                 products.weight,
                 (order_preferments.quantity-order_preferments.quantity_prepared) AS 
quantity_to_be_prepared,
          CASE pre_ferment_recipes.units
                WHEN 'kilograms'
                THEN 2.20462 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'pounds'
                THEN 1 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'ounces'
                THEN 0.0625 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
                WHEN 'grams'
                THEN 0.00220462 * pre_ferment_recipes.amount
          END  AS pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds,

          CASE pre_ferments.units
                    WHEN 'kilograms'
                    THEN 2.20462 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'pounds'
                    THEN 1 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'ounces'
                    THEN 0.0625 * pre_ferments.yield
                    WHEN 'grams'
                    THEN 0.00220462 * pre_ferments.yield
          END AS pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds

            FROM inventory
            LEFT JOIN pre_ferment_recipes ON pre_ferment_recipes.inventory_id = inventory.id
            LEFT JOIN dough_pre_ferments ON dough_pre_ferments.pre_ferment_id = pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            LEFT JOIN products ON products.dough_id = dough_pre_ferments.dough_id
            LEFT JOIN pre_ferments ON pre_ferments.id = pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            LEFT JOIN order_preferments ON order_preferments.preferment_id = pre_ferment_recipes.pre_ferment_id
            ) sq
            GROUP BY id
) AS t1 ON t.id = t1.id
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Does anyone think it is possible to combine the queries without using a UNION? Confirmed, this query works. However, before I select that green check box I want to make sure this is the only way.

Comment: it is possible to combine with joins, but I don't know everything that goes into your structure and it would take a while to learn it all. if you can get it from inventory table on both queries they can be joined.. it would be a lot better

Comment: @user2094495 let me look into it a bit.. i may be able to come up with a quick solution.

Comment: @user2094495 ok so you can do this with a join... the only thing is it'll be really similar to the union because you have to do your case calculations for each of the different quantities.. would you like to see what the query would be?

Comment: Sure if you don't mind. You're definitely getting the check mark now, you are my hero. Thank you so much. I always try to get my code as clean as possible for readability, fewer lines is better in my mind.

Comment: Perfect! Yes I wanted the inventory pounds as well thank you very much. The new query is shorter by 2 lines too! Haha. Great work my friend.

Comment: @user2094495 glad I could help! you did most of the work though! credit goes to you on all those calculations :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say performance is not an issue, you can use a `UNION`, and the an aggregate function to get the sum.

First, you will have to rearrange the columns of the queries in order to perform the union. You need to have same columns in the same order. So I will add `inventory_pounds` to the second query as a `0`, you can write appropriate SQL to get it correctly. (Or you could leave out `inventory_pounds` from the first query, if that's possible).

```
SELECT id, title, inventory_pounds, SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds / dough_recipe_yield_pounds * weight *      
quantity_to_be_baked) as amount_needed_for_orders,
        FROM (...)
        GROUP BY id

SELECT id, title, 0 as inventory_pounds, SUM(pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds / 
pre_ferment_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * quantity_to_be_prepared) as 
amount_needed_for_orders
        FROM (...)
        GROUP BY id
```

Then you can perform a `UNION` on two queries:

```
(SELECT id, title, inventory_pounds, SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds ...)
UNION
(SELECT id, title, 0 as inventory_pounds, SUM(pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds ...)
```

Now this may contain duplicate `id`s. So do a `GROUP BY` with `SUM`.

```
SELECT id, title,
       SUM(inventory_punds) as sum_pounds,
       SUM(amount_needed_for_orders) sum_amount_needed_for_orders
FROM
(SELECT id, title, inventory_pounds, SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds ...)
UNION
(SELECT id, title, 0 as inventory_pounds, SUM(pre_ferment_recipe_ingredient_pounds ...)
GROUP BY id, title;
```

Comment: If I can't figure out a way to combine the two queries into one I will get this UNION idea into action. Thanks for the idea.